# Is it possible to conclude that the mean of a set is greater than the mean of another set based on means of subsets?

Tags: statistics, proof-writing, descriptive-statistics

Problem 8 of Chapter 2 in Sheldon M. Ross' 5th edition of *Introduction to probability and statistics for engineers and scientists* is worded as follows:

> The sample mean of the weights of the adult women of town A is larger than the sample mean of the weights of the adult women of town B. Moreover, the sample mean of the weights of the adult men of town A is larger than the sample mean of the weights of the adult men of town B. Can we conclude that the sample mean of the weights of the adults of town A is larger than the sample mean of the weights of the adults of town B? Explain your answer.

I tried to describe the problem as precisely as possible in algebraic terms. Here is the description I wrote:

Given:

$$\bar x_{w,A}>\bar x_{w,B} \tag{1}$$
$$\bar x_{m,A}>\bar x_{m,B} \tag{2}$$

Where $$\bar x_{w,A} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n_{w,A}} x_{w,A,i}}{n_{w,A}} \tag{3}$$
$$\bar x_{w,B} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n_{w,B}} x_{w,B,i}}{n_{w,B}} \tag{4}$$
$$\bar x_{m,A} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n_{m,A}} x_{m,A,i}}{n_{m,A}} \tag{5}$$
$$\bar x_{m,B} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n_{m,B}} x_{m,B,i}}{n_{m,B}} \tag{6}$$

Can we conclude that $$\bar x_A > \bar x_B$$?

Where $$\bar x_A = \frac {\sum_{i=1}^{n_{w,A}} x_{w,A,i} + \sum_{i=1}^{n_{m,A}} x_{m,A,i}}{n_{w,A}+n_{m,A}} \tag{7}$$

$$\bar x_B = \frac {\sum_{i=1}^{n_{w,B}} x_{w,B,i} + \sum_{i=1}^{n_{m,B}} x_{m,B,i}}{n_{w,B}+n_{m,B}} \tag{8}$$

My first intuition was to rearrange (3) and (4) into (9) and (10):

$$\bar x_{w, A} n_{w, A} = \sum_{i=1}^{n_{w,A}}x_{w,A,i} \tag {9}$$
$$\bar x_{w, B} n_{w, B} = \sum_{i=1}^{n_{w,B}}x_{w,B,i} \tag {10}$$

Substituting (9) into (7) and (10) into (8) results in the following:

$$\bar x_A = \frac{\bar x_{w,A}n_{w,A} + \bar x_{m,A}n_{m,A}}{n_{w,A}+n_{m,A}}$$
$$\bar x_B = \frac{\bar x_{w,B}n_{w,B} + \bar x_{m,B}n_{m,B}}{n_{w,B}+n_{m,B}}$$

I am basically stuck here. How do I formally show whether we can conclude that $\bar x_A > \bar x_B$? How can I turn this into a formal mathematical proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If women on the whole weigh less than men and town $A$ has a higher proportion of women the mean adult weight can be lower in town $A$.  For a simple example, assume A has three women weighing $1.1$ and one man weighing $2.1$ while B has one woman weighing $1$ and one man weighing $2$.  The mean adult in $A$ weighs $1.35$ while the mean adult in $B$ weighs $1.5$

Comment: Your answer is correct and pointed me in the right direction. However, I ended up doing a bit of my own research because I wanted to dig deeper. If you are interested, please take a look at the answer I have provided... would be curious to hear your thoughts on it.

Answer (score 1):

We cannot in general say anything about a trend in the population based on trends within subgroups of the population, and often the reverse of what we would expect is true. This phenomenon is called [Simpson's Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox) and it is well documented in real world experiments, in particular for gender-based partitions of the population.

Comment: Thanks. I had a look at the original 1951 paper by Simpson and it looks quite intimidating.  How can I mathematically apply the paradox to my description of this particular problem?

Comment: To disprove such a statement, all you need is a counterexample. It's probably a fun and instructive exercise to come up with your own counter-example. As noted by @Ross Millikan in his answer, the key is a non-uniform distribution between the two partitions of the population.

Answer (score 0):

I scoured through the internet and books on mathematical proof to build up a *very* rudimentary idea of how to construct a basic mathematical statement and evaluate whether it is true or not. Rephrasing the proposition as a conditional statement helps a lot here, namely:

$$\boxed{\text{IF } (\bar x_{w,A}>\bar x_{w,B} \text{ AND } \bar x_{m,A} > \bar x_{m,B}), \text{THEN } (\bar x_A > \bar x_B)}$$

Where the hypothesis $P$ is ($\bar x_{w,A}>\bar x_{w,B}$ and $\bar x_{m,A} > \bar x_{m,B}$) and the conclusion $Q$ is ($\bar x_A > \bar x_B$). As mentioned by @Ross Millikan showing a statement is false basically boils down to finding a counter example. The following table outlines all the possibilities in the context of a conditional statement:

\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline P & Q & P \implies Q \\ \hline T & T & T \\ \hline T & F & F \\ \hline F & T & T \\ \hline F & F & T \\ \hline  \end{array}

Disproving the entire conditional statement would put us in row 2 of the above table. That is the only situation where $P \implies Q$ is false. The whole conditional statement being false implies that $Q$ is false. If I had to write this using my basic notions of this proof notation I would write $ \neg (P \implies Q) \implies \neg Q $. In English:

> The negation of P implies Q itself implies the negation of Q, or that Q is false

Therefore, finding a counterexample to $\text{IF } (\bar x_{w,A}>\bar x_{w,B} \text{ AND } \bar x_{m,A} > \bar x_{m,B}), \text{THEN } (\bar x_A > \bar x_B)$ itself implies that $(\bar x_A > \bar x_B)$ is false.

The other formulas in my initial question are basically *definitions*. They are assumed to be true in the context of the conditional statement and no proof of them is sought as far as I understand.